# Break lines in blade translation files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my view I have

```
<p>{{ trans('mission-vision-page.mission-description') }}</p>
```

I've put a block of text in my language file, but I want to maintain the new lines. I've tried:

1.

```
return ['mission-description' => 'line 1 <br /> line 2']
```

2.

```
return ['mission-description' => 'line 1 \n line 2']
```

3.

```
$newLine = '<br />';    
return ['mission-description' => 'line 1 ' . $newLine . ' line 2']
```

I know probably there's a better way to accomplish this, but in my en.php file can I add new lines?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` and `<br/>` tag in you message

```
<p>{!! trans('mission-vision-page.mission-description') !!}</p>
```

Comment: Perfect!, The difference is that {!! !!} doesn't escape the data and "puts" the HTML as HTML indeed, right? That's what I got from this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-this-vs-that?page=0 (After reading your answer, of course)

Comment: Any issues with the security if used `{!! !!}` in translations?

Answer (score 1):

Add custom blade directive, in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` add:

```php
\Blade::directive('lang2br', function ($expression) {
   return "<?php echo nl2br(app('translator')->getFromJson({$expression})); ?>";
});
```

Then you can use like `lang` directive:

```
@lang2br('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use the `@lang` blade directive, you can override the helper yourself using the following code:

```php
 Blade::directive('lang', function ($expression) {
    // @see Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesTranslations.php::compileLang()
    if (is_null($expression)) {
        return '<?php $__env->startTranslation(); ?>';
    } elseif ($expression[1] === '[') {
        return "<?php \$__env->startTranslation{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    return "<?php echo nl2br(app('translator')->getFromJson({$expression})); ?>";
});
```

This is basically a copy of the helper code in the `vendor` dir (`Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesTranslations.php::compileLang()`) with an `nl2br` wrapped around the output. This converts any newlines to `<br />` tags.