# how to break line in laravel language files?

Tags: laravel

How to add line break in laravel language files?
I have tried to use 
,
, \n\r, 
 to break line and add new line but all these not work.

```
return [
     'best_hospitality' => 'Simply <br /> the best hospitality',
 ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break lines in blade translation files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727515/break-lines-in-blade-translation-files)

Comment: @Digvijay No sir. that tags work only on balde template. not for message.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
'best_hospitality' => "<pre>Simply\r\nthe best hospitality</pre>",
```

or `'best_hospitality' => sprintf ('<pre>Simply%sthe best hospitality</pre>',PHP_EOL ),`

please note the use of **double quotes** in the first example, it is not working with **single quotes** if you use the \r\n inside the string, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) is why

if you try  `echo(Lang::get('message.best_hospitality'))` you will see the new line:

I am not so sure if you need the **pre tag**, depends where you need to use the Lang for html or not, eg using (**double quotes** here):

```
'best_hospitality' => "Simply\r\nthe best hospitality",
```

and `var_dump(Lang::get('message.best_hospitality')); exit;`

has the output

```
C:\wamp64\www\test\app\Http\Controllers\TestController.php:24:string 'Simply
the best hospitality' (length=39)
```

Does this cover your case?

Answer (score 0):

You need `HTML Entity Names` on your `lang` files.
Try this :

```
return [
     'best_hospitality' => 'Simply &lt;br&gt; the best hospitality',
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest creating a custom helper function for this specific case?

Add this into your `helpers.php` file:

```php7
if (! function_exists('trans_multiline')) {
    /**
     * Retrieve an escaped translated multiline string with <br> instead of newline characters.
     */
    function trans_multiline($key, array $replace = [], string $locale = null): string
    {
        return nl2br(e(__($key, $replace, $locale)));
    }
}
```

Now you will have a function `trans_multiline()` available for you in any view, which will behave pretty much like the built-in `__()` helper.

The function will fetch a localized string of text and replace any newline `\r\n` symbol with `<br>` tag.

Caveat: For a proper escaping it must be done before `nl2br()` function, like you see in the code above. So, to prevent any weird errors due to double-escaping, you must use this custom helper without any additional escaping, like so:

```php7
{!! trans_multiline('misc.warning', ['name' => 'Joe']) !!}
```

Escaping will be handled by the `e()` function (which is what Laravel uses under the hood of `{{ }}`) inside the helper itself.

And here's how you define a multiline translation string:

```php7
'warning' => "There's only 1 apple, :name!\r\nDon't eat it!"
```

Make sure to use double-quotes, so PHP actually replaces `\r\n` with a newline character.

Obviously, parameter replacing still works exactly like with the `__()` helper.